# How to use Lambda (java.util.function, java.util.stream) for Api Level below 24?

Tags: java, android, lambda, android-api-levels

I found several questions similar but no solution to my problem.

**What I tried**:

- I have written several methods that uses lambda with
  'java.util.function' and 'java.util.stream' (I use it in my Java
  application server side, on Windows)
- I STRONGLY NEED to use them in Android app (client side)
- I updated to Android Studio 3.0
- I configured build.gradle for java1.8, etc..., as required in "https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support.html", where it is also written that 'java.util.function' and 'java.util.stream' are available with api level >= 24
- I tried enabling jack option, but I have to disable, because during compiling Android Studio gives me error and says me to disable jack option.
- I STRONGLY NEED compatibility with api level lower than 24: minSdkVersion 15

**Problem**

- The compiling in Android Studio is OK, but when the app is installed on mobile with Api<24 I get a lot of errors in logcat and the app is not runned: example of errors:

  - 12-26 10:59:14.245 6709-6709/? W/dalvikvm: Link of class 'LVarie/Utilities_Per_Cache$$Lambda$5;' failed
  - 12-26 10:59:14.245 6709-6709/? W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve static field 2526 ($instance) in LVarie/Utilities_Per_Cache$$Lambda$5;
  - etc....

**Question:**

- How can I do when the Android device has api level < 24 (most of my users have mobiles with api level < 24) ?
- I understood, googling, that jack option (or retrolamda library) allows to use 'java.util.function' and 'java.util.stream', so is there a way to say  (I suppose inside gradle.build): if api level is <=24 use jack option?

Comment: you are saying like I tried, can you able to tell what went wrong

Comment: @Sree  You are right... I edit again the question with the problem...

Comment: It's the case of devices not supporting Java8 SDK. As far as I can tell, device is shipped with exactly the version of SDK the vendor chose, which is defined by version of API the vendor selected. So, you will not be able to use any newer methdos on API level that doesn't support Java8.

Comment: mmm... but I understood that before api 24 it was possible to use lamda enabling jack option or using retrolambda library. So I suppose it should be a solution...